# Failing to upgrade a WPF app from .Net Framework 4.8 to .Net Framework 4.8.1 due to Nuget error NU1201

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, nuget, .net-4.8

I have a WPF project built on .Net Framework 4.8 and packaged using [Windows Application Packaging Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net). When I tried to upgrade it to .Net Framework 4.8.1 for ARM64 support, I am getting [NU1201](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1201) error during Nuget restoration.

> NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362). Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)

I have tried to trim everything down to a minimum reproducible repo [here](https://github.com/aries-zhang/WpfApp7):

There are 2 [tags](https://github.com/aries-zhang/WpfApp7/tags):

- `netframework48` and
- `netframework481`

Their difference is switching over to ".Net Framework 4.8.1" in the project properties view:

[image]

On `netframework48`, run `nuget restore .\WpfApp7.sln` successfully restores the packages, while on `netframework481`, the same command fails with the following error message.

```
> nuget restore .\WpfApp7.sln
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '17.3.1.41501' from 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: D:\Work\temp\WpfApp7\WpfApp7\obj\project.assets.json
Restored D:\Work\temp\WpfApp7\WpfApp7\WpfApp7.csproj (in 69 ms).
Restoring packages for D:\Work\temp\WpfApp7\WpfApp7.Package\WpfApp7.Package.wapproj...
NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362). Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-arm. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-arm-aot. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-arm64-aot. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-x64. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-x64-aot. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-x86. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-x86-aot. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: D:\Work\temp\WpfApp7\WpfApp7.Package\obj\project.assets.json
Failed to restore D:\Work\temp\WpfApp7\WpfApp7.Package\WpfApp7.Package.wapproj (in 500 ms).

Errors in D:\Work\temp\WpfApp7\WpfApp7.Package\WpfApp7.Package.wapproj
    NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362). Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
    NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-arm. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
    NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-arm-aot. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
    NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-arm64-aot. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
    NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-x64. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
    NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-x64-aot. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
    NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-x86. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)
    NU1201: Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with uap10.0.18362 (UAP,Version=v10.0.18362) / win10-x86-aot. Project WpfApp7 supports: net481 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1)

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Users\arieszhang\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.FallbackLocation.config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

Feeds used:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
1 of 2 projects are up-to-date for restore.
```

Searched around but still did not figure out what this error exactly means? and how to fix this issue? In my project there is neither a project dependency nor a dependency from NetStandard to NetCoreApp as the [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1201) of the error says.

I have tried every UWP target in the WpfApp7.Package properties, but the error remains regardless which min version selected, so I'm assuming the UWP target version is unlikely the cause.

[image]

Same question is also cross posted here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/discussions/12206

---

Updates on 12 Nov 2022:
There is a great answer in the above github issue. Please see it there: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/discussions/12206#discussioncomment-4082656.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here for all supported Windows versions of .NET Framework 4.8.1 (found in [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-framework-481/#supported-windows-versions)):

> Windows Client versions: Windows 11, **Windows 10 version 21H2, Windows 10 version 21H1, Windows 10 version 20H2**

So from that piece of information, I'd say Windows 10 `10.0.18362` aka Windows 10 version 1903 is way too old for .NET Framework 4.8.1.

Comment: I suspected so too, so I tried to change the min target UWP version to the latest Windows 11 22H2 (10.0.22621) but still getting the same error (except the error message became "Project WpfApp7 is not compatible with `uap10.0.22621`").